# Cumulative count in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cumulative-sum, cumulative-frequency

We have a database with invoices from different clients with the date that the invoice was created.

We now want to calculate a cumulative count of the invoices for each customer. Invoice 1 of customer X should show in a new column "1", Invoice 2 of customer X "2" and so on. For the next customer it should start again from "1".

Which formulas can we use for this problem?

| Client | Created on | Cumulative count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mar-14 | 1 |
| 1 | jun-15 | 2 |
| 1 | dec-16 | 3 |
| 2 | feb-14 | 1 |
| ... | ... | 2 |

Comment: `COUNTIFS` with variable ranges.

Comment: Sample data with expected output will help here. Also, please include your own attempt at solving this to show where you are stuck at.

Comment: @JvdV I included a table of sample data. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2)`.

Comment: If one has acces to `BYROW` you could spill the count: `=BYROW(A1:A7,LAMBDA(myrow,COUNTIF(A1 :INDEX(A:A,ROW(myrow)),myrow)))`

Comment: Or using LET: `=LET(data,A1:A7,spill,COUNTIF(OFFSET(data,,,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(data,,0))),data),FILTER(spill,spill<>0))`